# Show and Hide keyboard leads to lag when keyboard resize the windows

Tags: android, keyboard, lag

I will try to explain this issue the best I can,  don't hesitate to ask more details if you think it can help. I can't put the whole file because it is a complicated app and a professional one.

Lets go !

I got one Activity that contains a google map view and host a FrameLayout where I can push multiple fragments.

Fragment A contains 3 EditText and one button.

My activity keyboard mode is SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE, so when keyboard showed up inside Fragment A the window is resized. Until here there's is no problem.

But when keyboard show up in a Fragment A with 4 - 5 other fragments (added and not replaced) in backstack the resized process takes more then 1 sec and it looks really bad. And when I hide it, the same thing again 1 sec lag then window resized.

I did try multiple solutions, but they are all workarounds, and I want to understand why resizing is not working properly.

Also, the application doesn't have big leaks in my knowledge.

Help! Please.

Comment: probably it is due all `4-5 other fargments`' views are too heavy, and they have to be resized as well, which takes much time.

Comment: Can I force them to not resize? There is no point, keyboard will never show on these fragment? @VladMatvienko

Comment: the point is that it shows in **activiy**, not in **fragment**. Therefore, all fragments, which are in Activity are affected. I think you should not look for workaround to make fragments not resize, but start **replacing** fragments instead of **adding** new ones on top of old ones.

Comment: Okey, I will look for in this direction.

Comment: Thanks mate ! So easy to find, I am to stupid ! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is the answer, as @VladMatvienko sayed, Activity is resize by keyboard and so all fragments inside. If they are too heavy it can leads to crash.